# Eclipse generate getters and setters does not encapsulate

Tags: java, eclipse, encapsulation, setter, getter

When I do quick fix on a field in eclipse I can generate a getter and setter for the field. This also makes the field private und subsequently transforms all access for this field in all source files to use the getter and setter. This is the case for a single field.

However if I do contextmenu > Source > Generate Getters and Setters... (the option to use when you want to affect all fields) it does not make the beforementioned change and all access to the fields in the source code is left as is.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 6):

The quick fix is not going to this menu. The menu that the quick fix call is accessible from `Context Menu -> Refactor -> Encapsulate Field`

Comment: CTRL-1 (I thought that was quickfix shortcut) offers "generate getter and setter" and this opens the window you describe (encapsulate). This is the feature I describe in the first part of my post. correct me if I'm wrong. My problem is that Source > Refactor does not encapsulate any fields, unlike the refactor > encapsulate field. I could do Refactor > Encapsulate field for all my fields but I'm kinda lazy..

Comment: When you use Ctrl-1 and go to `Generate getter and setter` it will give you the `Encapulate Field` screen. The name is confusing. If you look the `Generate getters and setter` documentation you will see it clealy: It says `Starts the 'Encapsulate field' refactoring to create getter and setters`. They probably should have named it better.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in batch? eg. select 20 fields and say: encapsulate all of them?